# Make SRC script wait for User Input Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, input

I'm trying to get a variable value (account) from the user and then send it to my script. I'm using this code:

```
<p><input type="text" id="accountField"=>Enter Number</input>
<button onclick="test()">Submit</button></p>
<script>
    function test(){
        var getAccount = document.getElementById("accountField").value;
        console.log(getAccount);
        return getAccount;
    }
    var account = test();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

The problem is that the src script runs without waiting for the user input and so it fails. I've tried the defer='defer' but that didn't make it wait.

I just need to get one number from the user and add it to my script as a variable. I was able to get it to work using the windows prompt, but I would rather avoid that if possible.

EDIT: I'm trying to make a synchronous call, not an asynchronous call. I am getting some information from a form and then making a call with that information. I don't want to call the external script unless the user answers the question in my form.

Comment: "I don't want to call the external script until the user answers the question in my form." — The "until" in that sentence makes the task asynchronous!

Comment: Can you suggest a better way for me to get the variable to my script? That is my real issue. I need to pass a piece of data to my external script and I have no idea how.

Comment: Make the content of the script a function. Call that function when you have the data.

Comment: `var account = test();` will call the function on page load. You probably don't want this! You have the click handler on the button, leave it up to that.

Comment: @JonP - I was trying to get the result of test out of the function and into my variable account.  This is the only way I knew to get it to work. I will research other ways. Thanks!

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't seem like you can wrap a <src> script in a function, but I will keep trying.

Comment: You put the code that is in the script in a function.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the element after your input has been read, no?

Something like:

```
var account, injected // Create the state variables

function injectScript(src) {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = src
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
    injected = true
}
function test(){
    const getAccount = document.getElementById("accountField").value

    // Probably want to do this to keep `account` up-to-date when the event handler runs
    account = getAccount
    account && !injected && injectScript('test.js')
}
test()
```

Comment: This still doesn't wait for the user to type something into the input before it calls `test()`.

Comment: Now it does @Quentin